# How to query four points of MBR covering all city points in country: SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, spatial-query

I will query four point of Minimum Bounding Rectangle covering all city in country on SQL Server. Now, I can only find POLYGON of a city in Thailand. This is my SQL command.

```
 DECLARE @TH geometry
 SELECT @TH=Geom
 FROM AirPollutionPM25
 WHERE country='Thailand' AND Year=2016

 SELECT @TH.STEnvelope().ToString()
```

This is a result of query but it's not correctly yet because it cover a city in Thailand.

[image]

and this is my data.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

That query will just assign the last value to `@TH`.

Try one of the aggregate functions. e g

```
 DECLARE @TH geometry
 SELECT @TH=geography::EnvelopeAggregate(Geom)
 FROM AirPollutionPM25
 WHERE country='Thailand' AND Year=2016

 SELECT @TH.STEnvelope().ToString()
```